# What the diffrence between thoses declaration - Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to create an application for fun (in Kotlin, on Android Studio), I tried different syntaxe for initialise my `var nb`.

The first case works but for the second I have `This variable must either have a type annotation or be initialized`, and i would like to know why.

Thanks for your answer

```
var nb = Random().nextInt((30 - 0))

var nb2
nb2 = Random().nextInt((30 - 0))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For second one, try this:

```
var nb2:Int
nb2 = Random().nextInt((30 - 0))
```

You specify first that your variable is **Int** and then you will give value to it.

Answer (score 5):

You can't declare a variable without either defining its data type:

```
var nb: Int
```

or initializing it:

```
var nb = Random().nextInt((30 - 0))
```

in which case its data type is inferred by the data type returned from the expression that is assigned to it, in this case `Int`.

Answer (score 1):

You must specific type for variable when declare in kotlin, because kotlin is Static typed languages. In the first case kotlin auto know what type of variable. In second case, it doesn't know type

Answer (score 1):

In your first declaration, kotlin auto cast `nb` to `Int`, because type of `Random().nextInt((30 - 0))` is `Int`.

In kotlin, when you join assignment and declaration within 1 line, it will be auto cast to the type of assigned value.

But if you seperate them in 2 lines, it will not work. You'd specify its type manually.

```
var nb2 : Int
nb2 = Random().nextInt((30 - 0))
```